# on window resize change div height in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

`.content-block` class content dynamic text, so height is different to each div block. Using javascript max height of div find apply to other div's so on browser resize all div will same height. Below pseudo code working in most of the browser, but in chrome, browser resize less than 320x480 will not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getMaxHeight(){ 
    return maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".content-block").map(function (){
         return $(this).height();
     }).get());
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.content-block').css('height', 'auto');
    $('.content-block').css('height', getMaxHeight);
});

$('.content-block').css('height', getMaxHeight);
</script>
<style>
.content-block{
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: you can do the same using `display: table-cell`.. no need of javascript here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use css flexbox for this purpose, using JavaScript might lead to scaling issues. Here is [CSS-Tricks Reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)